# Weekly scheduling of circleci job?

Tags: jmeter, scheduled-tasks, circleci

I would like to run jmeter tests in weekly basis. 
I have the below code now:

```
nightly:
  triggers:
    - schedule:
        cron: "0 0 13 ? * SAT *"
        filters:
          branches:
            only:
              - master
              - beta
```

Does it run everyday because of `nightly:` or does it run weekly because of `cron: "0 0 13 ? * SAT *"`. If it is daily, how can I convert to run weekly?

Comment: This likely won't run at all as you imagine because CircleCI doesn't support the advanced parts of Cron. Meaning you can't use question marks, math, and "SAT". You can only use an asterisk is integers. I'd suggest following the link in macbeccam's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"nightly" is just the name of the Circle CI workflow. It could just as easily be "foo" or "bar". The scheduling is in the cron line, where you specify 5 things: the Minute, Hour, Day of the month, Number of the month and Day of the week that you want the job to run.

For example, to run the workflow every Saturday at 1 pm, you could use "0 13 * * 6".

Using the asterisk (*) in a field means any value of that field is acceptable. Be aware that Circle CI will interpret the time as UTC so you may need to adjust it based on your timezone. https://crontab.guru/ is a nice site for learning about and experimenting with cron entries.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to know one more thing. Should i keep this commands under job:   or save level as job: ???